# How to run vtkRenderWindow in background without display it to user

Tags: c++, vtk

Im working in code which can create coronal, saggital, and axial image from dicom file, but In the same time I dont need to display renderWindow to user, and this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   // Verify input arguments
   if ( argc != 2 )
   {
      std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0]
      << " FolderName" << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   std::string folder = argv[1];
   //std::string folder = "C:\\VTK\\vtkdata-5.8.0\\Data\\DicomTestImages";

   // Read all the DICOM files in the specified directory.
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
   reader->SetDirectoryName(folder.c_str());
   reader->Update();

   // Visualize
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
   imageViewer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
imageViewer->SetSlice(0);
  imageViewer->Render();

for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){

cout<< k << endl;

if(k == 0){
imageViewer->SetSliceOrientationToYZ();
}else if(k == 1){
imageViewer->SetSliceOrientationToXZ();
}else{
 imageViewer->SetSliceOrientationToXY();
}
    int _MinSlice = imageViewer->GetSliceMin();
        int _MaxSlice = imageViewer->GetSliceMax();

     // Screenshot  
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter> windowToImageFilter = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter>::New();

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter> writer = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter>::New();
for (int i = _MinSlice; i < _MaxSlice; i++){
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter> windowToImageFilter = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkWindowToImageFilter>::New();

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter> writer = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPNGWriter>::New();

  windowToImageFilter->SetInput(imageViewer->GetRenderWindow());
  windowToImageFilter->ReadFrontBufferOff(); // read from the back buffer
  windowToImageFilter->Update();

  std::string filename = "img/" + std::to_string(k) + "/" + std::to_string(i) + ".png";
  char *y = new char[filename.length() + 1];
  std::strcpy(y, filename.c_str());

  writer->SetFileName(y);
  writer->SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter->GetOutputPort());
  writer->Write();

  imageViewer->SetSlice(i);
  imageViewer->Render();
}
}

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

my issue is when try `imageViewer->SetRenderWindow(NULL);` Or `imageViewer->GetRenderWindow()->Delete();` its will remove renderWindow instance, and code will be break, so that how I can keep renderWindow work in background without display it to user?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SetShowWindow(bool) or ShowWindowOff(), these methods are inherited from vtkWindow. Doing so should not stop the rendering pipeline (you can probably still use windowToImageFilter) but tbh I did not test it. Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you, Its work, and windowToImageFilter is work too, but to make sure, after inherit method, we need to use `SetOffScreenRendering` nested of SetShowWindow....so that the `imageViewer->GetRenderWindow()->SetOffScreenRendering(true);` make job work perfect.