# headless VTK for tests

Tags: python, vtk, headless

I have a simple VTK Python code that plots a tetrahedron:

```py
# plot a tetrahedron
import numpy
import vtk

node_coords = numpy.array(
    [
        [1.0, 0.0, -1.0 / numpy.sqrt(8)],
        [-0.5, +numpy.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0, -1.0 / numpy.sqrt(8)],
        [-0.5, -numpy.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0, -1.0 / numpy.sqrt(8)],
        [0.0, 0.0, numpy.sqrt(2.0) - 1.0 / numpy.sqrt(8)],
    ]
) / numpy.sqrt(3.0)
cells = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
cell_id = 0
line_width = 3.0


def get_line_actor(x0, x1, line_width=1.0):
    source = vtk.vtkLineSource()
    source.SetPoint1(x0)
    source.SetPoint2(x1)
    # mapper
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())
    # actor
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    # color actor
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0, 0, 0)
    actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(line_width)
    return actor


# Visualize
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

for ij in [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]:
    x0, x1 = node_coords[cells[cell_id][ij]]
    renderer.AddActor(get_line_actor(x0, x1, line_width))
renderer.SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

[image]

I would now like to add continuous integration testing for this code (which runs in in a headless environment), but all I'm getting is

```
Received 'aborted' signal
```

Adding code for closing the window

```py
# renderWindowInteractor.Start()

render_window.Finalize()
del render_window, render_window_interactor
```

does not help.

How to use VTK in a headless environment?

Comment: The actual code is more complicated, but yes, I want to prove that the code works. We're talking CI here; I've adapted the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I understand you feel the problem is due to the fact your CI system is headless, so in other words, that there's a problem when your test tries to render something? Did you try using vtkWindowToImageFilter to save an image and see if the rendering works or if it crashes trying? Or maybe I did not understand the problem?

Comment: @L.C. I could try that. If instead of displaying the scene, I could generate an image file (using mostly the same code), I'm happy. In fact, I wouldn't even need a file, I just want to make sure that (most of) the code runs without error.

Comment: Supposing the error is related to rendering on headless system, you could simply try to make the window not visible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206460/how-to-run-vtkrenderwindow-in-background-without-display-it-to-user/56208112#56208112

Comment: @L.C. On which object can I set `ShowWindowOff`? It's not `renderWindow`...

Comment: It's inherited from vtkWindow: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkWindow.html

Comment: Aha, it's not present in 7.1 though https://vtk.org/doc/release/7.1/html/classvtkWindow.html. This is the version used in Debian, Ubuntu etc.

Comment: Ouch. Then try using OffScreenRenderingOn (), otherwise you'll need a more recent build.

Comment: @L.C. Yeah, I think that'll be the case. I already opened a bug at Debian. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=929390

Comment: Building VTK from the sources is really not a big deal. When you run "make install" (after building) it also deploys the Python wrapper.

Comment: @L.C. Actually I can't think of a bigger package to build than VTK. (Perhaps ParaView.) It would need to be done at every test (travis or circleci), so that's a no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's the `Render` call that makes VTK throw. For unit tests, I could just comment out those lines

```
if render:
    renderWindow.Render()
    renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

The rest of the code will execute properly even in a headless environment.